# Can an IP address get you caught?

Tags: tails, help, fingerprinting, javascript, global-adversary

We need to use java scripts on some sites because we need them in order to get the task done. Suppose some site get my real IP address by using some java script attack, then how dangerous it can be? My IP address is a static not a variable one. It is different everytime and shows location several miles away each time than the last time. Maximum it shows a city and the name of my ISP. If my adversary is someone like the NSA or FBI can they use this info to get me?
Edit: I am using Tails and it protects against the fingerprinting. So even they install something on my system for attacking me in the long term, it will get deleted everytime I reboot or shut down my system, right?

Answer (score 1):

The NSA or the FBI (or the equivalent agency in your country), if they suspect illegal activity, can contact your ISP with a subpoena. Your ISP is legally bound to give requesting agencies the name and address of the person paying the bill. It is an extreme case, but it can be done.

Comment: Well even then how can a ISP trace me when i am using a variable or a public ip address? Isn,t catching me only possible when i am using a static ip ?

Comment: @Anonymousscum Your ISP "lends" you that IP address. Every ISP has a pool of IP addresses they assign the their users. They log every IP address you use with timestamps and other information. So no, they can catch you even if you don't use a static IP.

Comment: Seriously man i hate the sites which requires java script to function:( Because java scripts are known for leaking IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take some additional measures to keep a global adversary at bay.

1. Connect to internet at a public place which does not employ a security camera.
2. Use internet at that place only for one day and never use that place for internet connection again. This public places you use for internet connection need to be at least 100 miles away from your place of residence, and work or study.
3. Use Tails on a brand new notebook that you use for nothing else except for this purpose and get ride of the notebook's hard drive.
4. You need to isolate each activity from any other activity all the times. The best practice is to reboot the Tails after each separate activity.
5. Do not use internet for more than few hours at each location.
6. Use encryption all the time.
7. Pay attention to your surrounding at all times. If it does not feel right, move from that place.
8. leave your cellphone or any comminiucation device you carry at home.
9. Finally have a back up plan in case you are caught.

And yes, The IP address is more than enough information to catch you if you are wanted.

Comment: Well travelling daily 100 miles is impossible just for getting your daily job done.I guess that,s why someone said maintingin anonymity is a very difficult task or may be you are exageratting a little bit. Also why i need to get a new notebook or destroy it,s hard disk when the tails is not going to use the hard disk ? It uses RAM and RAM memory gets wiped out when it starts again .

Comment: @Anonymousscum Dear Anonymousscum, The intentions are different than practice. To give you an analogy, The labor is pretty much routine practice from beginning of time; and have been practiced billions of times; but there is still the risk of mother and/or child mortality during labor. The programmers are human and subject to error in judgement, mistake, short sightedness, and even worst. So while the intentions are admirable, the practice does not always follow the intentions. You only need to look at the record of how many flaws have been discovered during last 2 year effecting Tor and Tails

Comment: @Anonymousscum Looking at the records, one only get directed to practice prudence. Dealing with an adversary who has thousands of times more budget and resources than you do and Tor or Tails do, one can not be careful enough. To answer you bluntly, one can not put all of the responsibiliy of anonymisation on Tor and Tails. They are human working on those project and they make mistakes from time to time and quoting directly from horses mouth: look at it in next comment.

Comment: @Anonymousscum  "Tor doesn't protect you from a global adversary
A global passive adversary would be a person or an entity able to monitor at the same time the traffic between all the computers in a network. By studying, for example, the timing and volume patterns of the different communications across the network, it would be statistically possible to identify Tor circuits and thus matching Tor users and destination servers.
It is part of Tor's initial trade-off not to address such a threat in order to create a low-latency communication service usable for web browsing,

Comment: @Anonymousscum Internet chat or SSH connections." The NSA and similar entities are prime example of global adversary. While Tor and Tails explicitly tell you that they can not protect you against global adversary, it is unwise to assume otherwise or take the adversary lightly. you do not need to destroy the hard drive. You only need to uninstall that and remove that physically from your laptop just in case something went wrong. And no there is no exaggeration. If anything, this is on the side of not being strict enough.

Comment: @Anonymousscum For more information look at the Tails warning page: https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning/index.en.html